# What is the function variable visibility in solidity?

Tags: solidity

If I don't specify the function variable as storage or memory, what should be the default keyword?

Comment: It is an error if you don't specify the default visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Variable state defining is important for new versions of solidity. Storage variable stores permanent storage in blockchain and is quite expensive to use. Memory variable is stored temporarily and is cheaper to use.

[Reference](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-solidity-memory-vs-storage-which-to-use-in-local-functions-72b593c3703a#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM4ZjM4ODM0NjhmYzY1OWFiYjQ0NzVmMzYzMTNkMjI1ODVjMmQ3Y2EiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.YqQPNnlIzHfLt1AO-tgdQSA7WXSYkmUN627f6MTqydob38r1HUlUHpIne6j-dwxQZ3C4UhI28MS-TN-hZ_bpuWrqed_u8TEm3daL4li5cNFwlVsvuXTOiRNn4OrJQHK4R0rYjQ9Du4lf8wD_WvA8P4EJUVcKLW2fhQBsToKLBwKBgyAYMfefXMyyf8np3BAMzv2knekPwhJYh-9_98g8uLyPHp8d-JPmoxNiTxpKxy32AtOIhFEF8Ff_SHsccKL3sOIKw0GLGM99NN9AAX2hxVHwEZGbgU4tklbAyKx3iqvbV6QlxyIKoYMc49ozb6745hhv8VQ1oppdNzdkcjdjXw)

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring a variable that is storing a string then it is an error if you do not specify the variable as storage